# failed to lunch this command

Tags: ros, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i try this command :  `roslaunch panda_moveit_config demo.launch rviz_tutorial:=true`

i get this error :

```
No such file or directory: /opt/ros/noetic/share/franka_description/robots/panda_arm_hand.urdf.xacro [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/noetic/share/franka_description/robots/panda_arm_hand.urdf.xacro'
RLException: while processing /home/chizu/ws_moveit/src/panda_moveit_config/launch/planning_context.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/noetic/lib/xacro/xacro', '/opt/ros/noetic/share/franka_description/robots/panda_arm_hand.urdf.xacro']] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param if="$(eval arg('load_robot_description') and arg('load_gripper'))" name="$(arg robot_description)" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find franka_description)/robots/panda_arm_hand.urdf.xacro'"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384900/failed-to-lunch-this-command/) by [nizar00](https://answers.ros.org/users/82029/nizar00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2021-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As written in [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/blob/71ff2e06cdbe3ebb51ef67933dc068909ba9dec9/CHANGELOG.md) in [franka_ros](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros) (0.8.0 - 2021-08-03):

> **BREAKING** Remove panda_arm_hand.urdf.xacro. Use panda_arm.urdf.xacro hand:=true instead.

you should change line in

> /home/chizu/ws_moveit/src/panda_moveit_config/launch/planning_context.launch

which previously written as:

```
<param if="$(eval arg('load_robot_description') and arg('load_gripper'))" name="$(arg robot_description)" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find franka_description)/robots/panda_arm_hand.urdf.xacro'"/>
```

become,

```
<param if="$(eval arg('load_robot_description') and arg('load_gripper'))" name="$(arg robot_description)" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find franka_description)/robots/panda_arm.urdf.xacro' hand:=true"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [rizgiak](https://answers.ros.org/users/82292/rizgiak/) with karma: 106 on 2021-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin-ye](https://answers.ros.org/users/82412/yin-ye/) on 2021-08-27**:
Worked for me, thanks super much!

**Comment by [Donjaga](https://answers.ros.org/users/82133/donjaga/) on 2021-08-29**:
Thanks a lot, dude it works!

**Comment by [patelrishi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/82783/patelrishi1994/) on 2021-08-30**:
Thank you, It worked.